# NSMutableArray check with IndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I store touched Items from my UICollectionView into a NSMutableArray, then reloadData.

My question is, how can I check if IndexPath.row is equal to any of my NSMutableArray objects?

I can do something like:

```
if(indexPath.row == [myMutableArray objectAtIndex:0])
```

But in this case, it will check only for first object from my NSMutableArray, I want to check all available objects if any of them are == to indexPath.row

I'm a beginner, and trying to figure out.

Thanks.

Comment: To figure it out, read the docs (on NSArray). Think about methods like `indexOfObject:`. Or `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:`.

Comment: how do you store a row into an array? you can't just add it, as it isn't an object.

Comment: You should be wrapping your row integer in an NSNumber.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I'm assuming you are correctly storing values in `myMutableArray` as `NSNumber`s.

If you need to know the position in `myMutableArray`, use `indexOfObject:`:

```
NSUInteger position = [myMutableArray indexOfObject:@(indexPath.row)];
if (position != NSNotFound) {
    // handle object appearing in the array
}
```

If you just need to know whether the object appears in the array, use `containsObject:`:

```
if ([myMutableArray containsObject:@(indexPath.row)]) {
    // handle object appearing in the array
}
```

Comment: indexPath.row is not an object and there-for can't be present in an array.

Comment: funny that this answer got excepted, as it clearly won't work.

Comment: lol, this answer SHOULD have gotten excepted instead of accepted. Whatever that means...

Comment: It's a simple fix. I replaced uses of `indexPath.row` with `@(indexPath.row)`.

Answer (score 4):

for(int i=0 ; i < [myMutableArray count] ; i++)
{

```
   if(indexPath.row == [[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:i]integerValue])

    {
          NSlog(@"equal");
          // your actions
    }
   else
   {
           NSlog(@"not equal");
          // your actions
   }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

```
  if (indexPath.row == [[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue])
            {
            }

   // Change your if Condition with that Code it will helps you.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSNumber *num=[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row];
NSInteger anIndex=[myMutableArray indexOfObject:num];
if(NSNotFound == anIndex) {
    NSLog(@"not found");
}else {
    // anIndex contains the index. Do whatever you want.
}
```

Hope this helps .. :)

Comment: indexPath.row is not an object and there-for can't be present in an array.

Comment: yeah, I see it. better, but actually why did you posted a copy of Brigham's answer in the first place?